# iTunes music sync: "Albums" sub-window too tall for main window

Tags: itunes, windows, macos

iTunes version 12.3.0.44 running on Windows 7 X64 with a 1920x1200 monitor.

When a device is connected there is a window where you can manage what music gets synced to the device.  This scrollable top-level window contains 4 scrollable sub-windows labeled Playlists, Artists, Genres and Albums.  The two lower sub-windows (Genres and Albums) are both too tall to fit entirely within the top-level window, even when iTunes is maximized. Thus scrolling in the Albums window is a tedious combination of scrolling the sub-window and then having to scroll the main window to see things at the top or bottom of the Albums list.

Here is a screenshot (reduced to 1/2 size) with the outer window scrolled so that the top of the "Albums" sub-window is at the top of the main window.

[image]

Note that the bottom scroll arrow is off-screen because the Albums sub-window is too tall, even with the main window maximized at 1920x1200.
The only way to see the bottom few lines of the Albums sub-window is to scroll the *main* window down, as shown here:

[image]

Except now the top of the Albums window is cut off and the scroll button is not visible.

Is it possible to tweak something to reduce the height of the Albums (and Genres) windows so they fit?

Also, this is clearly a UI bug.  I'd love to know why obvious stuff like this remains uncorrected across many releases of the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion from someone ("turingtest2") on the Apple Community forum was to submit this as a bug on Apple Developer Connection, which I have done.

The bug number is 23139220.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for the detailed version numbers and bug report.